# Installing Ubuntu on Mac pro laptop problem

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 16.10

I am trying to install Ubuntu on Mac Pro laptop.  I faced an installation error when I boot from (USB). Here is a screenshot of the booting window:

[image: Error screenshot]

I am not familiar with Linux yet. Does anyone know how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Why did you tag 16.10?   Ubuntu 16.10 (the 2016-October release) is well since EOL (*end-of-life*) so trying to install that makes no sense, and is off-topic here due to EOL status.  The oldest supported release here is 18.04 (or the 2018-April release being supported until 2023-April or 5 years as a LTS or *long-term-support* release)

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  *I see reference to 16.04 in your picture; a 16.04 HWE kernel*